# Find which interval a number belongs to

Tags: java, scala, data-structures

I have a large set of intervals (start, end) that are continguous and non overlapping.  Given a number, I want to find out which interval it belongs to.

I am currently coding up a binary search based solution - I wanted to know if this would be possible using standard library data structs such as TreeMap or a TreeSet.

Comment: Are you using Guava?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Comment: You can use `TreeMap`, `TreeSet` or `Collections.binarySearch()`. It'll be easier to give a more specific answer if you can provide some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do using standard Java's or Scala's `TreeMap` (which is RB tree underneath).

Code:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

val ranges = TreeMap((1, 5), (8, 10), (11, 18))

def contains(intervals: TreeMap[Int, Int])(el: Int) =
  intervals.to(el).lastOption.exists(_._2 >= el)

(-1 to 20).foreach { i =>
  println(s"$i ${contains(ranges)(i)}")
}
```

Prints:

```
-1 false
0 false
1 true
2 true
3 true
4 true
5 true
6 false
7 false
8 true
9 true
10 true
11 true
12 true
13 true
14 true
15 true
16 true
17 true
18 true
19 false
20 false
```

The idea is to use `to` method, that returns a projection of the map with keys smaller or equal to the given element. If your map contains the interval that intersects given point, then this interval will be the largest key in the projection. So the only thing left is to check that the value (right boundary) of that interval is larger than the element in question.

Both `to` and `lastOption` methods work in `O(log n)` for RB tree.

This implementation assumes that ranges are inclusive, but it should be easy to modify this code for exclusive ranges.

Comment: ah perfect, I was just poking around the scala docs for TreeMap. floorEntry and higherEntry also seem like relevant methods. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly, you have a List of ranges like (1,5), (6,10),(11,18) and so on. When given an input like 4, you want to return the range which contains this input.

Here is a version in Scala:

```
scala> val input = List((1,5), (6,10),(11,18))
input: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,5), (6,10), (11,18))

scala> input.filter(elem => 4 <= elem._2 && 4 >= elem._1)
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,5))
```

You can expand on this by extracting this into a method and pass the input parameter.

You could replace the type of collection that you want depending on the use case. Have a look here at the collections performance characteristics:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

If you want to use a TreeSet, you could do the following:

```
scala> val in = TreeSet((1,5),(6,10),(11,15))
in: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[(Int, Int)] = TreeSet((1,5), (6,10))

scala> in.filter(elem => 4 <= elem._2 && 4 >= elem._1)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[(Int, Int)] = TreeSet((1,5))
```

Comment: The input requirements are correct - however,I want to do find the answer in logN time since the list of ranges is really big

Comment: Take a look at the edited post and let me know if that helps!

Comment: Did you look into the performance characteristics documentation? If you do so, you will know if filter runs in logN time

Comment: @sparkr `filter` that takes arbitrary predicate can't be faster than `O(N)` for collections. Take a look at the sources of `TreeMap`.